# Extjs Pagination tool is disabled when we service call returns empty data

Tags: extjs, pagination

When we give service data as null to extjs with pagination,then it is disabling the pagination tool bar.

We have some requirement like we have a filter button on enabling we will show filtered data at first and remaining pages as empty. Total count will be the same.

**Example**:

If we have 1000 records as total and the page size is 50, then we have total pages size will be 20. If we enable filter then we will get 500 records which are filtered, then, in that case, we will show total records as 1000 (Actual size without filter) and from 11 page onwards we will show empty pages by returning empty records.

**Issue**:

When we return empty records to Extjs,it is disabling the pagination, we want 'next page' to be disabled but we need ' the previous page' button to be enabled

Is it possible in Extjs?

Do you have any idea why it is disabling the pagination tool bar?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lo1)
`SERVER`: I'm using some free service to load data, where i have 10 records(5 per page) but i send `total: 15` from server to force toolbar displaying 3 pages. On the server, in query if `page === 3` i send empty array. Here's the [**CODE**](https://pastebin.com/E4NLvbZX)
`CLIENT`: In pagination toolbar i define `change` event listener, where i make sure buttons will be always enabled. Also make input, for page number, enabled + correct, with total page counter.

```
listeners: {
    change: function (cmp, config) {
       var store = cmp.up('grid').getStore();

       var numb = cmp.getComponent('inputItem');
       numb.setDisabled(false);
       numb.setValue(store.currentPage);

       var text = cmp.getComponent('afterTextItem');
       text.setHtml('of ' + (store.totalCount / store.pageSize));

       cmp.setChildDisabled('#first', false);
       cmp.setChildDisabled('#prev', false);
       cmp.setChildDisabled('#next', false);
       cmp.setChildDisabled('#last', false);
       cmp.setChildDisabled('#refresh', false);
   }
}
```